# Tikz drawing a shape with foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I have a shape drawing template that plots coordinates of vertices of a shape based on how many sides it has. However, with shapes with lots of sides having to type (a1)-(a2) so on so forth gets kind of tedious so I tried using a foreach loop. Something like

```
\draw
\foreach \s in {0,1,...,\m}
{
{(a\s)--
}
};
```

But this doesnt work and when i look at it i dont expect it to but I have no idea how else to go about it

Heres my code:

```
,tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{15};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\n};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\initialangle}{90+(\angle/2)(1-Mod(\n,2))};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\n-1};
\foreach \s in {0,1,...,\m}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\angle\s};
\coordinate (a\s) at (\initialangle+\r:3);
\draw (a\s) circle (0.1) node[above]{a\s};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{15};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\n};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\initialangle}{90+(\angle/2)(1-Mod(\n,2))};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\m}{\n-1};
\foreach \s in {0,1,...,\m}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\angle*\s};
\coordinate (a\s) at (\initialangle+\r:3);
\draw (a\s) circle[radius=0.1] node[above]{a\s};
}
\draw (a0)
foreach \s in {1,...,\m}{-- (a\s)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I treated the 0th coordinate differently, changed `\pgfmathsetmacro` to `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` where advantageous, added a multiplication sign `*` and `-- cycle`.

You may want to make it a bit more fancy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{15};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\n};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\initialangle}{90+(\angle/2)(1-Mod(\n,2))};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\m}{\n-1};
\path foreach \s in {0,1,...,\m}
{
 ({\initialangle+\angle*\s}:3) 
 node[circle,inner sep=0.5mm,draw,label={[circle,anchor={180+\initialangle+\angle*\s}]$a_{\s}$}] 
 (a\s) {}
}; 
\draw  foreach \s [remember=\s as \lasts (initially \m)]
 in {0,1,...,\m} { (a\lasts)-- (a\s)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there are many more ways to do this, including graph drawing libraries (see e.g. the example on the upper part of p. 274 of pgfmanual v3.1.5), chains (see the example on p. 604 of pgfmanual v3.1.5) or [letting the connections follow a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527141/194703).

Comment: Hehe that was simple. Thank you :D